# Get value checkbox javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an array of checkbox (to use with php), bu i want to use ajax to make somethings with this values from checkbox, i want to get the value from each checkbox and make an ajax request.

I have this:

```
$("#checked").each(function(i, val){
                var k = $(i).value();
                console.log(k);
            });
```

but no success.

html:

```
<input id="checado" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="78">
<input id="checado" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="79">
<input id="checado" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="80">
<input id="checado" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="81">
```

Comment: `this.value` or `$(this).val()`.

Comment: there should not be multiple elements with the same id on the page, you should use a class in that case, and select as `$('.checked')` instead.

Comment: The HTML with the checkboxes would also be helpful if you added it to your question (though the .val() hint might be all you need to make progress)

Comment: First thing do to is read the [`.each` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and figure which parameters are passed to the callback. As you can see, the first argument passed is the *index* of the element in the set, and the second argument is the element itself. So, why are you passing the index (a number) to jQuery? Second, if you [search for `.value`](http://api.jquery.com/?s=.value), you'll notice that there is no such method. I highly recommend to read the [jQuery tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/) before you continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small change to your HTML you can use the following JavaScript ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8YUkn/)):

```
<input class="checado" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="78"> 78<br/>
<input class="checado" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="79"> 79<br/>
<input class="checado" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="80"> 80<br/>
<input class="checado" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="81"> 81<br/>
<button id='Submit'>Submit</button>
<script>
  $('#Submit').on('click', function() {
    var values = []
    $('.checado:checked').each(function () {
        var e = $(this);
        values.push(e.val());
    });
    alert(values);
  });
</script>
```

For a more detailed breakdown of what is going on, the check boxes have a checked state and a value.  the jQuery Selector `$('.checado:checked')` will return just the checked check boxes (You should use `class` when you have multiple elements and `id` only when you are identifying a single element, browsers and CSS can appear lazy about this but incorrect usage will yield unpredictable results).  The other change is to grab the values by the jQuery method `.val()` which helps hide the input type and browser specific ways values are fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery, which uses it's own `.val()` method. Replace `.value()` with `.val()`.